# How can one count total records AND separately count records where two fields are equal

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let say I have the following table called VISITS:

[image]

I need to count the total records for each location, and then have a separate count of those records where `Date1` and `Date2` values are equal.  The final results should look like this:

[image]

I can get a count of total using:

**select Location, Count(*) as 'Total Visits' from Visits Group by Location**

And I can get a count of visits that match by doing

**select Location, Count(*) as 'Total Matched' From Visits
where Date1 = Date2 group by Location**

But I don't know how to do both counts with a single query.

Comment: In the future, please include table structures and sample data **as text in your question** - pictures require transcription, which is tedious and error-prone.

Comment: Tried. New to the site.  Saw no table insert in the tools. Copying and pasting from excel didn't work.  Tried making a little Ascii table, but the editor removed my formatting.  I'm sure I could figure it out eventually, but for expedience, I used the pictures. Sorry for any inconvenience this may have caused.

Answer (score 3):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select v.Location, Count(*),
       sum(case when v.date1 = v.date2 then 1 else 0 end) as same_day
from Visits v
group by v.location;
```

Note that your queries are missing the `group by` clause.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah that was just an oversight on my part. My real query is much more complex with some joins, but this was a simplification.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

a simple way could be

```
  select Location, Count(*), sum(case when Date1 = Date2 then 1 else 0 end)
  from Visits
  group by location
```

Comment: Perhaps this might work in other DBMSes, but SQL Server cannot convert the boolean expression `Date1 = Date2` implicitly to a numerical value (that `SUM` accepts). However, a usable numerical value for the boolean expression can be determined using a CASE-statement: `CASE WHEN Date1 = Date2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` will work fine as the argument for the `SUM` here.